# I can't save a VISIO .vsd file on my C Drive from Visual Studio?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visio

The following occurs when I try to save a VISIO file to C:\SimpleFlowchart.vsd via visual studio.

I used the <DispId(13)>

```
Function SaveAs(FileName As String) As Short
```

Command

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in VisioTestApp.exe

Comment: Make this an official answer and I will Green Triangle you. IT WORKED!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current versions of Windows really don't like it when you save stuff to the drive's root directory. If you can't save it in your Users folder, then at least make a temp directory off of C: and save it there